# GridView.ItemsSource breaks when Creating a New Window

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

When I run the code while Navigating to a new page:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), pages);
```

The code runs fine and produces the correct output when connected to the following code in BlankPage1.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        _thumbnails = e.Parameter as ObservableCollection<ThumbnailImage>;
        FileView.ItemsSource = _thumbnails;
}
```

But, when I run

```
CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
int newViewId = 0;
await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
                Frame frame = new Frame();
                frame.MinHeight = 800;
                frame.MaxWidth = 400;
                frame.MinWidth = 200;
                frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), pages);
                Window.Current.Content = frame;
                Window.Current.Activate();
                newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
});
bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
```

To create a new View and navigate to the same xaml file, it throws an exception: "Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Viewer.exe"

But, when OnNavigatedTo is changed to

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        _thumbnails = e.Parameter as ObservableCollection<ThumbnailImage>;
        //FileView.ItemsSource = _thumbnails;
}
```

There is no error, but the GridView is not populated.

The class is

```
public class ThumbnailImage
{
    public BitmapImage Source { get; set; }
    public StorageFile File { get; set; }

    public ThumbnailImage(BitmapImage source, StorageFile file)
    {
        Source = source;
        File = file;
    }
}
```

And the xaml is

```
<Page Width="300" Height="850"
x:Class="Viewer.BlankPage1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Viewer"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <GridView x:Name="FileView" Width="256" Height="850" Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ThumbnailImage">
                <Grid>
                    <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE894;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Image CanDrag="True" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{x:Bind Source}" Height="100" Margin="10,40"/>
                    <Border Opacity=".8" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
</ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an `ObservableCollection` (or any other `INotifyPropertyChanged`- or `INotifyCollectionChanged`-based model) between two different views in UWP is **not recommended**.

The reason is that each view in UWP has its own UI thread, which is also the reason you need to use the `Dispatcher` of the newly created view to navigate to your page. However, when you use data-binding any change to the collection will execute `CollectionChanged` which will **run for both app views**. This will inevitably crash the app because `CollectionChanged` and `PropertyChanged` influence the UI and hence must run on the specific view's UI thread - and in this case, each view has its own UI thread.

So to make sure you avoid these issues, create a new collection instead to make sure each view has its own `ObservableCollection` instance:

```
var secondaryViewPages = new ObservableCollection<ThumbnailImage>(pages);
frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), secondaryViewPages);
```

**Note**: in case `ThumbnailImage` implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you would also have to create a "copy" of each of the images in the collection. In this case however it is not necessary as `ThumbnailImage` is a POCO, and it will not notify its changes to the UI.

**Also note:** using a collection as the parameter of `Navigate` is not recommended, as it will prevent you from serializing the app state during app suspension, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate):

> Apps typically use GetNavigationState to serialize the frame’s state when the app suspends. You can do this directly in your app code or indirectly by using the SuspensionManager class generated by the Visual Studio templates. To enable frame state serialization using GetNavigationState, you must use only basic types for the navigation parameter, such as string, char, numeric, and GUID types. Otherwise GetNavigationState will throw an exception when the app suspends. The parameter can have other types if you do not use GetNavigationState.

Instead you could share data between views in a different manner like having a singleton service both views can access.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to change my code so that I passed a single object instead of an ObservableCollection and it worked.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential issues:

1. You may have to delay the call to `frame.Navigate` until the application has loaded. In your code example, you are trying to navigate before the Frame is assigned to `Window.Current.Content`. You might try moving it as the last line in the lambda block. You might even need to run the Navigate synchronously or at least on the UI thread.
2. The `RunAsync` may be causing issues. You can test by using `Dispatcher.Invoke` and see if it still has the same issue.